# octal string to integer for open(O_CREATE) permissions

Tags: c, atoi, octal, string-conversion

How to use an octal string from *argv[] for something like:

```
open("outfile",O_CREAT | O_RDWR,0777);
```

0777 means permission in octal numbers.

My code:

```
int arC = atoi(argv[optind]);
printf("argv optind %s after atoi %d\n",argv[optind],arC);
int test =des2=open("createfile",O_CREAT | O_RDWR,arC);
printf("fd %d\n",test);
```

Terminal output:

```
./copymaster -c 0777 in 
argv optind 0777 after atoi 777
fd 5
```

But permissions are not set to 0777. `open()` just ignores `arC`.

How to convert this string `argv[optind]` to a usable form for the `open()` command?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, but maybe you need [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/).

Comment: Just for get about the `ato*()` functions. They are unreliable, to not say useless, as they do not properly indicate conversion failures. Go for the `strto*()` family of functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) converts a string to integer when the string contains the integer in decimal representation.

But in your case the number is given in octal representation, so you cannot use `atoi`.

The [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) function is more general, because you can specify the base (8 in your case).

Replace

```
int arC = atoi(argv[optind]);    // convert decimal number
```

by

```
int arC = strtol(argv[optind], NULL, 8);   // convert octal number
```

With this modification your program would print this:

```
./copymaster -c 0777 in 
argv optind 0777 after strtol 511
...
```

`511` being `0777 octal` converted to decimal.

Comment: If you do not use the end-pointer (`dummy` here) just passing `NULL` would be OK.

Comment: Note that the leading `0` is not needed in `0777`, but no harm either.  IMO, a `0` should be given in the command and use `strtol(argv[optind], NULL, 0);` to allow hex/decimal input.